# What do you call a person who take down notes using their gadgets like laptops or Smart phones?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, british-english, vocabulary

Curiosity question though my friends called me "nerd Gadgets" because i always take down notes in class using my phone rather than the traditional pen and paper, but i think there is a better word to describe this?

Comment: Does [single word for extensive computer user, not geek nor nerd](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/275300/191178) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call such a person A
***DIGITAL NATIVE***.

I see them every day.

Most of my students are 'digital natives'.

I am not. I'm a digital immigrant.

Here's an example from Reverso.context.net:

For the so-called Digital Natives, it is quite obviously looking for products online, compare and buy.

According to Wikipedia:

"Digital native is a person that grows in the digital age, rather than acquiring familiarity with digital system as an adult, as a digital immigrant.
Both terms were used as early as 1996 as part of the Declaration of the Independence of Cyberspace.
They were popularized by education consultant Marc Prensky in his 2001 article entitled Digital Natives, Digital Immigrants, in which he relates the contemporary decline in American education to educators' failure to understand the needs of modern students. 
His article posited that "the arrival and rapid dissemination of digital technology in the last decade of the 20th century" had changed the way students think and process information, making it difficult for them to excel academically using the outdated teaching methods of the day. In other words, children raised in a digital, media-saturated world, require a media-rich learning environment to hold their attention, and Prensky dubbed these children "digital natives"."
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_native)

Comment: The sentence quoted from Reverso seems broken English to me.

Answer (score 0):

> **tech-savvy**
>   adjective
>   *informal*
>
> Well informed about or proficient in the use of modern technology, especially computers.
>   *-- [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tech-savvy)*