# Is there a name for the phobia of not having access to the internet?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, phobias

Nomophobia is the fear of being out of mobile phone contact.

Is there a name for the fear or phobia of being away from / not being able to reach the internet?

Comment: I propose "nonephobia".

Comment: *Nomophobia* only exists as a word because; a.) young people (who love coining neologisms) do often suffer from it, and b.) it's a witty contraction of "no mobile phone". Since the current crop of mobiles are often Internet-connected, OP could probably just use the word anyway.

Comment: Forget about the internet: is there a word for the fear of not having access to StackExchange?

Comment: @Danielδ I know I suffer from noELUphobia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a word for precisely this fear (yet), but if you want a fancy-sounding neologism, here is *fear of away from Internet* in transliterated Greek: *macriapodiadictuophobia*.

If you apply the same technique in Latin, the result would be *abinterretemetus*.

(In case you're wondering about good ole English, it turns out that it's much more ghastly: *awayfrominternetfear*.)

However, if you could use words that connote more of an addiction to the internet, then the answers to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/39296/10041) may suffice: *cybernaut*, *nethead*, and *netizen*.  Most macriapodiadictuophobes *are* netheads, and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

Fear of the internet would be *interretephobia*, so perhaps fear of being away from it would be *abinterretephobia*.

Comment: Wouldn't that be *abinternetephobia*?  Or is the *n* replaced on purpose?

Comment: @Danielδ: The Latin for 'net' is 'rete'.

Comment: Why not use English?  Then you'd have three languages contributing.

Comment: @Danielδ: Too obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the word is 'discomgoogolation.'

Check [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/discomgoogolation):

> Discomgoogolation: *a feeling of anxiety felt by someone who is unable to access the internet*

Note that the word is *informal.*

Comment: Never heard this before – fancy way of saying _FOMO_!